# I want to write a command that outputs information about the server. I ran into the error

Tags: discord, discord.py

i I want to write a command that outputs information about the server. I ran into the error

My code:

```py
    @client.command( pass_context = True )
    async def server( ctx ): #server
        emb = discord.Embed( title = '<:rightgrey:927573354863542292> Kuromi | Информация', description = f'<:ccrown:928503495361982605> **Владелец:** {ctx.guild.owner.mention} | `{ctx.guild.owner.name}`', colour = 0x2f3136, url = '' )
        emb.add_field(name=f"Пользователей: {ctx.guild.member_count}", value=f"Участников: {ctx.guild.members}\nБотов:")
        await ctx.send( embed = emb )
    #{ctx.guild.member_count}
    client.run('') #твой токен бота
```

Именно часть с `{ctx.guild.members}` отказывается работать, выводя такую ошибку:

```py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\vlad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
        await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
      File "C:\Users\vlad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
        await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\vlad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
        raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
    discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
    In embed: Embed size exceeds maximum size of 6000
```

and I don't really understand how to display the display of the number of bots!

Answer (score 1):

`ctx.guild.members` returns full list of all members. Therefore a size of your embed is very big and Discord can't display it.

If you want to display member count use `ctx.guild.member_count` instead of `ctx.guild.members`.

To display number of bots use something like this:

```py
sum(member.bot for member in ctx.guild.members)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
# I Transtalted from english to russian using Google Translator, It might not be perfect

# Learn more about textwrap from the two links below
#   1. https: // docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html
#   2. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/textwrap-text-wrapping-filling-python/
import textwrap

# Code for a basic discord bot
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="--")


# Command
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.guild_only() # to make sure that this command will only work on a discord server
async def server(ctx):

    # Send this embed first with the basic facts
    emb = discord.Embed(title='<:rightgrey:927573354863542292> Kuromi | Информация',
                        description=f'<:ccrown:928503495361982605> **Владелец:** {ctx.guild.owner.mention} | `{ctx.guild.owner.name}` \n Пользователи: {ctx.guild.member_count}\nВесь список участников будет отправлен вам в директ',
                        color=0x2f3136)  # its `color`, not `colour`
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)

    # Creating a string with the member names of the discord server seperated by a newline("\n")
    all_members = "\n".join(ctx.guild.members)

    # Creating chunks of texts with the maximum amount of characters of 4096
    # and using each chunk as the description of the embed
    # This will create a huge amount of embeds if the amount of members are high
    # This could be used to spam the server channel
    for chunk in textwrap.wrap(all_members, 4096, replace_whitespace=False):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="<:rightgrey:927573354863542292> Kuromi | Список членов",
            description=chunk,
            color=0x2f3136
        )
        # Send the member list embed messages to the user who ran the command
        # To prevent spam in the channel
        # Change `ctx.author.send` to `ctx.send` to send to the channel instead of DM
        await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)

# Run the bot
client.run("TOKEN")
```